# R: Remove vector elements from vector elements

Tags: r, vector, gsub

I think the title is a bit confusing, but here my problem:
I have 2 vectors, one containing some text the other one containing some phrases

```
text <- c("this is some text","some elements should be removed", "i hope you can help me with this text element problem")
pattern <- c("text", "some","be")
```

And now I want to remove all elements from `pattern`which are in text, so as result vector

```
text_result
[1] "this is"
[2] "elements should removed"
[3] "i hope you can help me with this element problem"
```

I tried

```
text_result <- sapply(pattern, function(x) gsub(x, text, replacement =""))
```

or

```
text_result <- sapply(text, function(y) sapply(pattern, function(x)gsub(x,y,replacement ="")))
```

but in both cases I receive a large matrix with

```
length(pattern)*length(text) elements
```

thanks in advance!

Comment: `gsub(paste0(pattern, collapse = "|"), "", text)`

Comment: worked fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
`%notin%` <- function(x,y) !(x %in% y)
 lapply(strsplit(text," "),function(x) paste(x[x %notin% pattern],collapse=" "))
```

Comment: also worked fine, returning a list, Thanks!